# Why is this echoing the values that don't match?

Tags: php, strpos

I believe I am setting the `if(strpos());` correctly. I've tried setting in a `else{};` and `elseif {};` after seeing it in a few examples, but they prompted for unexpected `'}'` and so forth.

```
<?php

$extension = '.com';

$lines = file('testdomains.txt');

foreach($lines as $line)
{
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false)
    $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
    echo $line;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code

```
if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false)
$line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
$line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
echo $line;
```

should be

```
if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false) {
   $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
   $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
   echo $line;
}
```

you forgot to wrapper them ...

Comment: That'll do it! The example I took this whole time was wrong :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using if statements without the curly braces, remember than only one statement will be executed as part of that condition. If you want to place multiple statements you must use curly braces, and not just put them on the same line.

Your code should be like this

```
if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false){
    $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
    echo $line;
}
```